# What does two values separated only by parentheses on right side of = mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the meaning of two values separated only by parenthesis on the RHS of = in Keras?

```
LSTM_layer = LSTM(units=256)(embedding)
```

Full code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

sentence_input = Input(shape=(None,))
embedding =  Embedding(input_dim = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim = 100)(sentence_input)
LSTM_layer = LSTM(units=256)(embedding)
output_dense = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(LSTM_layer)
```

Comment: https://oswalt.dev/2015/05/double-parentheses-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just ordinary call syntax without a temporary variable. `LSTM_Layer = LSTM(units=256)(embedding)` is equivalent to

```
# assuming t isn't already defined
t = LSTM(units=256)
LSTM_Layer = t(embedding)
del t
```

Comment: This is first time I've seen this syntax and combined with the API for LSTM not showing  a  __call__ method it was still confusing. I found a reference here: http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM.html. Now this makes sense.

Comment: `__call__` is inherited from the base class `keras.layers.rnn.base_rnn.RNN`.